# Print out per item for each status it reached, the oldest datetime of that statuschange in a different column on the same row

Tags: mysql

I've got one table (Items) with items and another table (ItemStatusHistory) where the status history per item is recorded. Now I want to print out per item for each status it reached, the oldest datetime of that statuschange in a different column on the same row.

What is the best way to query the desired output table using MySQL? Please provide example to query this.

```
Table Items
+----+------+
| ID | Item |
+----+------+
|  1 | a    |
|  2 | b    |
|  3 | c    |
|  4 | d    |
|  5 | e    |
+----+------+

Table ItemStatusHistory
+----+--------+----------------+------------+
| ID | ItemID | StatusDateTime | StatusName |
+----+--------+----------------+------------+
|  1 |      1 | 2015-01-01     | statusA    |
|  2 |      2 | 2015-01-01     | statusA    |
|  3 |      3 | 2015-01-02     | statusA    |
|  4 |      1 | 2015-01-03     | statusB    |
|  5 |      1 | 2015-01-04     | statusC    |
|  6 |      2 | 2015-01-05     | statusB    |
|  7 |      3 | 2015-01-06     | statusB    |
|  8 |      1 | 2015-01-06     | statusA    |
|  9 |      2 | 2015-01-07     | statusA    |
| 10 |      3 | 2015-01-08     | statusC    |
+----+--------+----------------+------------+

Desired Output Table DateFirstReachedStatus
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Item | FirstReachedStatusA | FirstReachedStatusB | FirstReachedStatusC |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| a    | 2015-01-01          | 2015-01-03          | 2015-01-04          |
| b    | 2015-01-01          | 2015-01-05          |                     |
| c    | 2015-01-02          | 2015-01-06          | 2015-01-08          |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I tried following query, but I don't got the output I want.

```
select 
    i.Item,
    Min(status_A.StatusDateTime)[status_A],
    Min(status_B.StatusDateTime)[status_B],
    Min(status_C.StatusDateTime)[status_C]
from Items i
    inner join ItemStatusHistory status_A on i.ID = status_A.ItemID
    inner join ItemStatusHistory status_B on i.ID = status_B.ItemID
    inner join ItemStatusHistory status_C on i.ID = status_C.ItemID
where
    status_A.StatusName = 'statusA'
    and status_B.StatusName = 'statusB'
    and status_V.StatusName = 'statusC'
order by i.Item asc
```

Comment: Generally, `please provide` requests are not well received. Please try something, and if you have troubles, then are for help with the problem you are having.

Comment: What you need is called pivoting table or transpose rows to columns. In your case it should be dynamic because, I guess, there are many statuses. If not, please say so I can provide an answer. If Status can be many you will have to use a dynamic procedure here it is: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47902/how-to-transpose-convert-rows-as-columns-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @JorgeCampos, an item can have many statuses. I'll take a look to provided example.